# Response encryption problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I get the response as follow:

```
TIMESTAMP=2011%2d09%2d22T10%3a20%3a24Z&CORRELATIONID=fa0181684fd81&ACK=Success
&VERSION=65%2e0&BUILD=2133933&AMT=0%2e12&CURRENCYCODE=USD&AVSCODE=X&CVV2MATCH=M
&TRANSACTIONID=6PT23270XK626941N" in this encrypted format
```

How can I get original text string? This is my code for Parsing the URL :

```
NSString *parameterString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"USER=mercha_1316582882_biz_api1.ifuturz.com"
                              "&PWD=1316582974"
                              "&SIGNATURE=Az-qrCDOk-pVcMVvJLOJY7DrGESBAgSH4RGOILESJSsYaBlWVZ3mNfJB"
                              "&METHOD=DoDirectPayment"
                              "&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa"
                              "&ACCT=%@"
                              "&EXPDATE=092016 "
                              "&CVV2=111"
                              "&AMT=%@"
                              "&FIRSTNAME=%@"
                              "&LASTNAME=%@"
                              "&STREET=%@"
                              "&CITY=%@"
                              "&STATE=%@"
                              "&ZIP=%@"
                              "&COUNTRYCODE=IN"
                              "&CURRENCYCODE=USD"
                              "&PAYMENTACTION=Sale"
                              "&VERSION=65.0",
                              txtCreditCardNo.text,
                              strAmount,
                              txtName.text,
                              txtName.text,
                              txtAddress.text,
                              txtCity.text,
                              txtState.text,
                              txtZipCode.text
                              ] retain];

NSLog(@"Soap : %@",parameterString);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp"];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [parameterString length]]; 
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *resp;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&resp error:&err];

if (resp != nil) {



    NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"---------------------- %@",stringResponse);

    SBJSON *jsonParser = [SBJSON new];
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    json = [jsonParser objectWithString:stringResponse error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"\n \n JSN Dic : %@",[json description]);

} else if (err != nil) {

    NSLog(@"\n \n Nill");

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do more accurate...

Comment: This response i get :

TIMESTAMP=2011%2d09%2d22T10%3a20%3a24Z
&CORRELATIONID=fa0181684fd81
&ACK=Success
&VERSION=65%2e0
&BUILD=2133933
&AMT=0%2e12
&CURRENCYCODE=USD
&AVSCODE=X
&CVV2MATCH=M
&TRANSACTIONID=6PT23270XK626941N"


And i want this kind of Response :

TIMESTAMP=2011-09-22:10:20:3 24Z
&CORRELATIONID=fa0181684fd81
&ACK=Success
&VERSION=65.0
&BUILD=2133933
&AMT=0.12
&CURRENCYCODE=USD
&AVSCODE=X
&CVV2MATCH=M
&TRANSACTIONID=6PT23270XK626941N"


Means how can i remove characters like '%2' etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not encrypted, it is URL Encoded, that is troublesome characters are replaced with their hex values.  Ex: '%2d' is '-'.

```
NSString *stringToDecode = @"TIMESTAMP=2011%2d09%2d22T10%3a20%3a24Z&CORRELATIONID=fa0181684fd81&ACK=Success&VERSION=65%2e0&BUILD=2133933&AMT=0%2e12&CURRENCYCODE=USD&AVSCODE=X&CVV2MATCH=M&TRANSACTIONID=6PT23270XK626941N";

NSString *decodedString = [stringToDecode stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"decodedString: %@", decodedString);
```

NSLog output:

```
decodedString: TIMESTAMP=2011-09-22T10:20:24Z&CORRELATIONID=fa0181684fd81&ACK=Success&VERSION=65.0&BUILD=2133933&AMT=0.12&CURRENCYCODE=USD&AVSCODE=X&CVV2MATCH=M&TRANSACTIONID=6PT23270XK626941N
```