# How do I decode html coded characters in an NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, character-encoding, nsstring

I am writing an app with both english and french support. The app requests information from a server and the server response uses JSON. I am using the JSONKit library to parse the response but the strings its parsing from the french responses look like this:

`Membres &#8211;&#201;conomisez 5% sur les services et jusqu&#8217;&#224; 15% sur d&#8217;autres produits`

How do I decode the special characters? so that I get this:

Membres –Économisez 5% sur les services et jusqu’à 15% sur d’autres produits

I looked at the API for NSString and tried some of the instance methods but I don't know much about character encodings and I ended up getting some weird results. So if you can also provide a brief explanation on character encodings I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513312/response-encryption-problem/7514003#7514003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [these NSString categories](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m)

Comment: How would I go about using this? Probably a dumb question but I'm still fairly new to iPhone programming

Comment: Add that file and its matching h header file to your project. NSString will then have a new instance method called stringByDecodingHTMLEntities. NSString *decodedString = [encodedString stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked well for me if you're still using Objective C code.

```
- (NSString *)decodeHtmlStringValue
{
  NSData *encodedString = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSAttributedString *htmlString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:encodedString
                                                                    options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
  return [htmlString string];
}
```

If your using swift

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift](http://Swift%20example)

Answer (score 1):

NSString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding with the correct string encoding should do the magic.

```
[yourString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

might be a good candidate.

Comment: I tried: NSString *myString = [myOtherString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; but its returning null. I checked myOtherString and it contains the encoded string.

Comment: The documentation states: Returns nil if the transformation is not possible, for example, the percent escapes give a byte sequence not legal in encoding.

Comment: This is for percent decoding, the question is asking for html code decoding