# Decoding HTML in Swift causes BAD_ACCESS on iOS device

Tags: html, ios, xcode, swift, decode

Following the great example of [How do I decode HTML entities in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift) I have managed to decode a HTML entity. However, running my app in iOS simulator causes no errors while testing it on a real device do.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc)
```

On this line:

```
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!
```

How do you go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not running the code in the main thread. I am not sure  how it is working in the simulator. Anyway try putting that code in a main thread block like
 `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
{
  let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)
  let decodedString = attributedString?.string
})`

It should work properly.