# Equivalent of GTMNSString+HTML in swift?

Tags: ios, json, string, swift, html-entities

I have a string which contains HTML entities, e.g. `&#8217;` which I want to show up as `'`. I'm pretty new to swift, so I am not sure how I can change all HTML entities since I can't seem to find an equivalent of GTMNSString+HTML for swift.

I tried to use the solution here: [How do I decode HTML entities in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift), but it is REALLY slow, i.e. it takes very long for the strings to be ready and my page to show. I also have problems using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`, since there are always errors e.g. missing `)` or missing `,`etc.

Any advice on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/JigarM/Swift-Tutorials/tree/master/Swift-RSSFeed/Pods/MWFeedParser

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus This means that I will end up having extra stuff that I don't want. I will give tng's answer I try instead. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try importing GTMNSString+HTML in your Swift bridging header and access this objective-c class/function from your Swift code? I would look here for a primer on how to do this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: I was thinking of doing that too. I will look into it as well. Thanks for the suggestion. Will accept your answer if I can get it done successfully =P

Comment: Let me know if you need help. It should be relatively straight forward to import the objective-c header into the bridging header and then using those functions from Swift.

Comment: It seems so easy to add, but I can't use it =( I'm supposed to be able to use it normally right?

Comment: you should be able to just call <string>.gtm_stringByEscapingForHTML(), like "hello".gtm_stringByEscapingForHTML()

Comment: yea. I just figured that out. I just had to create a `NSString` first: `var testing:NSString` 
Thank you so much!