# How can I remove tag html from JSON in swift

Tags: html, json, xcode, swift

I am using data from JSON but can’t get rid of tag html,  ex. `<p> </p>  &#.#8217` I have followed all suggestion which have been posted in the forum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift) but it’s still not working. Please kindly help and suggest. Here are my codes

```
    @IBOutlet weak var nameUILabel: UILabel! 

    var dogs:JSON? {

    didSet {

        self.functionFood()
    }
}

   func functionFood() {

    self.nameUILabel.text = self.dogs?["title"].string


    }

   }
```

Comment: There's no specific ask here.  Can you provide a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
    var html2String:String {
        return NSAttributedString(data: dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!.string
    }
}


"<p>&#8217Paragraph1 Test&#8217</p><p>&#8217Paragraph2 Test&#8217</p>".html2String   // "’Paragraph1 Test’\n’Paragraph2 Test’\n"
```