# Replace html characters in Swift without lag

Tags: html, string, swift

I have used this simple extension to remove HTML special charactes it works fine but the problem is its **slow** is there any other method which can be used for clean and fast execution:

```
extension String {
  func htmlToString() -> String {
    return NSAttributedString(data: dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!.string
  }
}
```

ex: string with special character:

```
let strinWithCharacter = "Hello there &amp; this is a test string"
```

after using extension it replaces `&amp;` and return:

```
   let strinWithoutCharacter = strinWithCharacter.htmlToString() 
// "Hello there & this is a test string"
```

Comment: What is the list of characters you need to deal with?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30141700/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks that worked