# How do I decode HTML entities in swift 2.0?

Tags: html, swift

I [found this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25607542/1187415) on Stackoverflow. However, there was an error. How do I fix this error?

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSAttributedString' with an argument list of type '(data: NSData, options: [String : AnyObject], documentAttributes: NilLiteralConvertible, error: NilLiteralConvertible)'
```

Error is in "let attributedString".

```
extension String {
    init(htmlEncodedString: String) {
        let encodedData = htmlEncodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
        ]
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)! //ERROR HERE!
        self.init(attributedString.string)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:) I believe you have the correct method, but note that Swift 2 has error handling, so you would need to do:

```
extension String {
    init(htmlEncodedString: String) {
        do {
            let encodedData = htmlEncodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
                NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
            ]
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
            self.init(attributedString.string)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unhandled error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested that in a playground and it happily compiles.