# How to make use of a string extension

Tags: ios, swift2, extension-methods

I ma migrating over to Swift 2 and trying to resolve all the compile errors and have found the code the link below which is apparently the new way to process html text, but I cannot see how to use this in my functions in swift 2?

in swift 1.2 I used:

```
attributedText.appendAttributedString(htmlString.html2AttributedString)
```

and

```
extension String {

    var html2AttributedString:NSAttributedString {

        return NSAttributedString(data: dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding],
            documentAttributes: nil,
            error: nil)!
    }
}
```

This is the new way of doing it apparently [String extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922570/how-do-i-encode-html-entities-in-swift-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mentioned extension in the link  [How do I decode HTML entities in swift 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922570/how-do-i-encode-html-entities-in-swift-2-0) like the following

```
var str = String(htmlEncodedString: "abc");
```