# Swift 2 Json utf8 string character error

Tags: php, ios, json, swift2, utf8-decode

I have working `Json` file and app, but i have text `encoding` problem.

My `Json` file output example

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","data":[{"id":"21","title":"I&#039;m working on project","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cilliim adipisicin"}]}
```

`Json` Parse Functions, I added parsing some functions you can see under

```
    func initArrayCategory(){
        self.getResponseFromURL(self.getStringURLWithJSONFormatForUserAPI(URL_API_NEWS_CATEGORIES), withParams: nil, Success: { (operation, responseObject) -> () in
            if let success = responseObject[API_PARAM_STATUS] as? String{
                if success == "SUCCESS"{
                    if let data = responseObject[API_PARAM_DATA] as? NSMutableArray{
                        self.arrayCategory = data
                    }
                }
                self.Category.reloadData()
            }

            }, Failure: { (operation, error) -> () in
                if error.localizedDescription == "The network connection was lost."{
                    self.initArrayCategory()
                }
            }, showLoader: true, hideLoader: true)
    }



    func postResponseFromURL(strURL: String, withParams dictParams:NSDictionary?, Success:(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject:AnyObject!)->(),Failure:(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error:NSError!)->(),showLoader isShowDefaultLoader:Bool,showAnimated isShowLoaderAnimated:Bool, hideLoader isHideDefaultLoader:Bool)
    {

        let hudprogress = MBProgressHUD()

        if isShowDefaultLoader{
            MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
            hudprogress.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate
            hudprogress.labelText = "Loading"
        }

        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(array: ["text/html", "application/json"]) as Set<NSObject>

        manager.POST(strURL, parameters: dictParams, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in
            //println("RESPONSE DATA: " + responseObject.description)

            if isHideDefaultLoader{
                MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
            }

            Success(operation: operation, responseObject: responseObject
            )

            }) { (operation, error) -> Void in

                print("Response:    \(operation.responseObject)")
                print("Error:  " + error.localizedDescription)

                Failure(operation: operation, error: error)
                hudprogress.hide(true)
        }
    }



let URL_API_HOST:String = "http://www.blabla.com/Items/"

    func postResponseFromURL(strURL: String, withParams dictParams:NSDictionary?, Success:(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject:AnyObject!)->(),Failure:(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error:NSError!)->(),showLoader isShowDefaultLoader:Bool, hideLoader isHideDefaultLoader:Bool)
    {
        self.postResponseFromURL(strURL, withParams: dictParams, Success: Success, Failure: Failure, showLoader: isShowDefaultLoader, showAnimated: true, hideLoader: isHideDefaultLoader)
    }


    func setObjectToUserDefaults(object:AnyObject, forKey strKey:String, writeToDisk isWrite:Bool )
    {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(object, forKey: strKey)
        if isWrite{
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
    }



    func getStringURLWithJSONFormatForUserAPI(strAPI:String)->String{
        return self.getStringURLForUserAPI(strAPI, withJSONFormat: true)
    }


    func getStringURLForUserAPI(strAPI:String, withJSONFormat isJSON:Bool)->String{

        var strURL:String = self.getBaseURl()
        strURL += strAPI

        if isJSON
        {
            strURL = self.addJSONFormatInURL(strURL)
        }

        return strURL
    }


    func getBaseURl()->String{
        return URL_API_HOST
    }


    func addJSONFormatInURL(strURL:String)->String{
        return strURL + URL_API_FORMAT_JSON
    }
```

My view controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var detailTitle:String?
    var detailDesc:String?

    @IBOutlet weak var textim: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textbig: UITextView!

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    textbig.text = detailDesc
    textim.text = detailTitle


}
```

Mysql Table *Mysql* File

```
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `App`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `App`;
CREATE TABLE `App` (
  `id` int(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `image` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video` text,
  `likes` int(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visits` int(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Mysql Real Value from Table

```
('21', 'I&#039;m working on project', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.  ', '7292754.jpg', '', '2', '26')
```

Remote connect *Php* File

```
$db_host="my host";   // your mysql database host name
$db_username="myusername";  // username
$db_pass="my past";                 // password
$connnect=mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die("Databese Error, Please check your connection values !");  
@mysql_select_db ("App");  // Select Your Database


@mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
@mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
@mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

Remote *Php* File

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
include("connect.php");

$q = "Select * from App";
$r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {

    $arr = array();

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
            {
                $arr[] = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>"SUCCESS",'data'=>$arr));
        }
        else {
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>"FAIL"));
        }
```

**Output**

```
textim.text =  I&#039;m working on project
```

**must be**

```
textim.text = I'm working on project

json file coming title = I&#039;m working on project
```

Please help me

TY

Comment: Show how you load the JSON file. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Thilo added functions

Comment: And you are sure the entity-escaping is not already done by the server? Can you print the unparsed response?

Comment: @Thilo added functions inside

Comment: @Thilo I added server output and all mysql tables , json parse everything utf8

Comment: I cannot see where the JSON is parsed. There is too much code; please remove irrelevant code.

Comment: @Droppy here initArrayCategory() inside

Comment: So this looks like an issue with AFNetworking?

Comment: @Droppy yeah afnetworking

Comment: You might want to highlight that then

Comment: What produces the JSON server-side? Confirm that if you access it with something like `curl` the entity-escaping is not already done (because if it is, it's a server-side issue)

Comment: @Droppy yes i new added, also i think  we do utf8 decode for label.texts ?

Comment: @Thilo Im using Afnnetworking

Comment: I don't agree that is an issue with AFNetworking, rather with how you use it and lack understanding of what is happening. For example, why is there acceptable content type "text/html" if you expect "application/json", and if you expect "text/html" then you should handle it properly.

Comment: @A-Live using application/json you can see top side in function codes

Comment: @EricD. removed output same also i will add now remote php file contents

Comment: ADDED REMOTE PHP FILE ALSO

Comment: It's not an issue with AFNetworking. I would suspect the server end.  Have you examined what's actually in the database column?  How is the database populated?

Comment: @Droppy also i added remote connect.php you can see there in bottom encodings.

Comment: What's in the database?  Have you even looked?

Comment: @Droppy added mysql file

Comment: This is getting beyond a joke.  Please check the data in the database itself.  Not the database username/password/url or the database schema.  The data.

Comment: @Droppy added mysql real value from table

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper What you need is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Resolved, I think that codes need too many people !
Thanks @Eric D. I try your linked codes and i changed somethings and now working success !

Codes ;

```
if let detailanother =  detailTitle {


            do {
                let encodedData = detailanother.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
                    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                ]
                let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
                self.textim.text = attributedString.string
            } catch {
                fatalError("Unhandled error: \(error)")
            }


    }
```

Thanks for everyone !
 Good codings !