# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSAttributedString' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift

i followed this example to decode HTML values. [TO decode a json parsed value: answered by akashivskyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift)

I had this code and I am getting following error:

```
let encodedString = "The Weeknd &#8216;King Of The Fall&#8217;"

let encodedData = encodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
]

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!

let decodedString = attributedString.string
```

Error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSAttributedString' with an argument list of type '(data: NSData, options: [String : AnyObject], documentAttributes: _, error: _)'

Any help is appreciated to suggest ay answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `error` option from the `NSAttributedString` initializer and add the `try` instead:

```
let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: I think the error is to include exception handling code in the latest Swift 2.1.

Comment: right! i forgot the try.