# HTML Formatting in swift

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, uiwebview

I am getting a content like this from my web service

```
<Strong>some unicode characters</Strong>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<some_ID>" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

When I load this string directly to the `UIWebView` it is black. But I want to make it in white color.

1. How to change the color of this in swift
2. Also need to change the width of this video to current `UIView` width

How can I do this?

Comment: Seems duplicate, refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript to add a bit of style and resize the video:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let html = "..."
    webView.delegate = self
    webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("script", withExtension: "js")!
    let javascript = try! String(contentsOfURL: url)

    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(javascript)
}
```

And the content of `script.js`:

```
var title = document.body.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0]
title.style.color = 'blue'
title.style.display = 'block'

var iframe = document.body.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
iframe.style.width = '100%'
iframe.height = document.body.offsetHeight - title.offsetHeight
```

Comment: Thanks :) work perfectly for the color. But my video dissappear when web view finished loading? What would be the reason for this?