# Converting any UTF-8 encoded Characters in String in Swift from API

Tags: ios, swift, string, utf-8, nsstring

I am making an app for checking grades and assignments for my school. From the web when looking at an assignment you see this:
[image: Image from school web page]

But the server actually returns a string containing both regular characters while the Chinese characters stay in the regular UTF-8 Encoded form: 
[image: Raw string shown in the app]

How would I parse through the raw String in Swift and decode any UTF-8 encoded characters. . i am having a hard time trying to find and even figure out a solution for this online. Just an FYI i cannot change anything on the backend side.

Comment: Show the raw data you receive from the server (or, well, since raw data would just be a byte sequence, you probably do want to interpret it via the encoding, probably UTF-8). Is it HTML? XML? JSON? Show it as text, not a screenshot. Also, what you're seeing for the Chinese characters is not UTF-8 encoding. It looks like HTML/XML numeric character references. So, the most likely solution is to interpret the raw data not just as a string, but as HTML or XML, which will automatically handle those.

Comment: How does one interpret the string as HTML? @KenThomases

Comment: Well, on macOS, `NSAttributedString` can do it. That functionality is not available on iOS so you probably want to use a third-party library. Search for "ios parse html".

Comment: Compare [How do I decode HTML entities in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `NSAttributedString` to convert these HTML entities to string.

```
let htmlString = "test&#21271;&#20140;&#30340;test"
if let htmldata = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmldata, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil) {
    let finalString = attributedString.string
    print(finalString)
    //output: test北京的test
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution. Worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: its taking more time when do checking for more string

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to convert only numeric entities, you can use [`CFStringTransform(_:_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1542411-cfstringtransform).

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> func CFStringTransform(_ string: CFMutableString!, 
>                      _ range: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFRange>!, 
>                      _ transform: CFString!, 
>                      _ reverse: Bool) -> Bool
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **`transform`**
>
> A CFString object that identifies the transformation to apply. For a
>   list of valid values, see Transform Identifiers for CFStringTransform.
>   In macOS 10.4 and later, you can also use any valid ICU transform ID
>   defined in the [ICU User Guide for Transforms](http://icu.sourceforge.net/userguide/Transform.html).

(Code tested in Swift 3/Xcode 8, iOS 8.4 simulator.)

```
func decodeNumericEntities(_ input: String) -> String {
    let nsMutableString = NSMutableString(string: input)
    CFStringTransform(nsMutableString, nil, "Any-Hex/XML10" as CFString, true)
    return nsMutableString as String
}

print(decodeNumericEntities("from &#21271;&#20140;")) //->from 北京
```

Or if you prefer computed property and extension:

```
extension String {
    var decodingNumericEntities: String {
        let nsMutableString = NSMutableString(string: self)
        CFStringTransform(nsMutableString, nil, "Any-Hex/XML10" as CFString, true)
        return nsMutableString as String
    }
}

print("from &#21271;&#20140;".decodingNumericEntities) //->from 北京
```

Remember these codes above do not work for named character entities, such as `&gt;` or `&amp;`.

(From [this thread](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/20554/13972) in スタック・オーバーフロー(Japanese StackOverflow).)

Answer (score 1):

You have a handful of HTML/XML entities. You can convert them into "normal text" like this:

```c
// Class declaration in ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

```c
// Implementation of methods in ViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *xml = @"<root>&#21271;</root>";
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[xml UTF8String] length:[xml length]];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;

    [parser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
}
```

The log output is:

```
string: 北
```