# Trouble using NSString method, stringByReplacingOccurrenceOfString in swift

Tags: swift, nsstring

In this project I am trying to display a section of a webpage (weather-forecast.com) in my app. I've downloaded the html content into 'webContent' and used componentsSeparatedByString to break up the html code into an array of Strings to then grab the index I desire for my app. This part is in 'websiteArray[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ede1.png)' and this value is a string "Mostly dry. Very mild (max 17°C on Sat afternoon, min 8°C on Fri night). Winds increasing (calm on Fri night, fresh winds from the ESE by Sun night)."
It contains &deg instead of the symbol ° and I am trying to use the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString to replace &deg with °. I'm getting an that this method can't be called on a string but only NSString so then I tried converting my string to an NSString but now I am getting the error " [String] is not convertible to NSString".

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to convert to an array of NSString or an alternative way to use the stringByReplacingOccurrenceOfString method?

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/London/forecasts/latest")!

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let urlContent = data {

                let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                let websiteArray = webContent?.componentsSeparatedByString("3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:</b><span class=\"read-more-small\"><span class=\"read-more-content\"> <span class=\"phrase\">")



                if websiteArray?.count > 0{
                    //print(websiteArray![1])
                    var weatherArrayWithDeg = websiteArray![1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>")

                    // Need to convert to NSString to use stringByReplacingOccurenceOfString, want to separate '$deg;' for ' °'
                    let weatherArray = (weatherArrayWithDeg as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&deg;", withString: " °")

                    print(weatherArrayWithDeg[0])
                }

            }
        }

        task.resume()
```

[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but "&deg;" is a "HTML/XML entity", so this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift.

Comment: `weatherArrayWithDeg` is an *array* of strings.

Comment: Why isn't my weatherArrayWithDeg just a string? Since I am using the index 1 of websiteArray

Comment: Checking out that link now

Comment: @MartinR Thank you I was being dumb. Since its an array of strings i just accessed the first element and it worked. (weatheArrayWithDeg[0])

Answer (score 0):

I'll opt to solve your problem as opposed to your question:

Add as extension:

```
extension String {

    func convertFromHTML() -> String? {

        if let htmldata = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmldata, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil) {
            return attributedString.string
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let weather = "its 70&deg; outside"
print("weather: \(weather.convertFromHTML())")
```

Note you can now solve your problem on any string, in any part of your app, for any HTML that needs converted.  And that's cool.

Comment: Ok I am trying your method cause it does sound really convenient to know. I'm getting an error saying my value type String does not have a member 'data'. Am I supposed to make a var data and set it equal to something? I thought for a second that I should use my 'weatherArray' string but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: First see if you can get my `"its 70&deg; outside"` example code working to make sure you've implemented the extension and usage correctly.  If you get the example to work then edit your question with a screen shot of the error and I'll have a look.

Comment: I went ahead and tried the example code you provided and I'm getting the same error about the 'self.data' variable. I edited my question with a screenshot of the playground implemented it in

Comment: I can see you're not using Swift 3.0.  My example is in Swift 3.0 syntax.  I think yours will be something like self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding).  There will likely be other syntax errors.  You'll just have to make a few changes to get it in the right version of Swift for you.