# Cast Unicode within a string

Tags: ios, swift, unicode

I have an API that will return a String with Unicode inside of it, for example:

> Whether you think you can or whether you think you can't `&#8211;` you are right.

In the string above, `&#8211` is `-`.

Currently, I'm using `replacingOccurrences(of: "&#8211", with: "\"", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)` to replace any Unicode inside the returned String.  But once in a while I would get a Unicode that I didn't include in my list.

At the end of each returned String, I would use `+` to combine the string with the Author of the Quote.  When I use `UnicodeScalar` to cast the String, Xcode would give me `binary operator + cannot be applied to operands of type unicode and string` error.

I feel that my solution works, but it's not ideal. Is there a way to cast any Unicode with the returned String?

Comment: It seems the unicode string you get is a HTML-code. [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25607542/5571327)

Comment: @WeiJay Thank you for the link, that solves my problem.