# How to decode UTF-8 string in a UITextView

Tags: utf-8, swift3, uiwebview, uitextview

What is the proper way to decode UTF-8 encoded html and present the text in a UITextView while keeping the HTML formatting?

I have the following title:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Pasta and Pizza&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
```

After decoding:

```
<p><strong>Pasta and Pizza</strong><br />
```

Finally I would like to present the text in a UITextView that respects the HTML tags:

**Pasta and Pizza**

I am pulling this content directly from a database, so I simply can't pull the html page into a UIWebView. (I am not opposed to using a UIWebView.  I simply don't know how to implement that either.)

Comment: Are you able to decode the string to **<p><strong>Pasta and Pizza</strong><br />** ?

Comment: No @NiravD.  I used this tool:
http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode just to verify that it was in a UTF-8 format.

Comment: Related: [How do I decode HTML entities in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift)

Comment: I was able to solve this using a combination of @MartinR 's StringExtensionHTML on GitHub for replacing HTML entities with HTML markup, and creating an attributed string as Nirav D suggested.