# How to decode html formatted text in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want to display the below html text in iOS app

```
<p><span style="color: #000000;">Experience royalty in all its splendor</span><br /><span style="color: #000000;"> An address that is a possession of pride</span></p>
```

I tried with NSAttributedString and appending font in html string, however nothing works

```
let st:String = pjt.value(forKey: "description") as! String // Original content from API - "&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: #000000;&quot;&gt;Experience royalty in all its splendor&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: #000000;&quot;&gt; An address that is a possession of pride&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;........"

let desc:Data = st.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!
                //st.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)!
            do {
                let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(data: desc, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
                print("Attr STr \(attrStr)")
                self.textView.attributedText = attrStr;
            }
```

It's also not working in web view with `self.webView.loadHTMLString(st, baseURL: nil)`

**Updated**

Textview or webview or label all shows the same plain html string `<p><span style="color: #000000;">Experience royalty in all its splendor</span><br /><span style="color: #000000;"> An address that is a possession of pride</span></p>`

Any help?

**Note**: Swift 3

Thanks!

Comment: show some additional code

Comment: your `let st:String` wrong check once before update the string

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Ok

Comment: @MartinR it shows same html string <p><span style="color: #000000;">Experience royalty in all its splendor</span><br /><span style="color: #000000;"> An address that is a possession of pride</span></p> in textview

Comment: are you sure st variable is not nil?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry! Please check the updated question. Please let me know still its not clear

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes it's not nil

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please check the updated question.

Comment: The problem is that all HTML markup is quoted, e.g. `&lt;` instead of `<`. Do you have any chance to change the API? Otherwise using `stringByDecodingHTMLEntities ` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30141700/1187415 should solve the issue.

Comment: Ok Thanks! @MartinR Will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is

```
"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: #000000;&quot;&gt;Experience royalty in all its splendor&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: #000000;&quot;&gt; An address that is a possession of pride&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
```

with all HTML markup encoded as HTML entities. The string must be transformed to

```
<p><span style="color: #000000;">Experience royalty in all its splendor</span><br /><span style="color: #000000;"> An address that is a possession of pride</span></p>
```

**before** passing it to the attributed string. This can for example
be done using the `stringByDecodingHTMLEntities` method from [How do I decode HTML entities in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift/30141700#30141700):

```
let st  = (pjt.value(forKey: "description") as! String).stringByDecodingHTMLEntities
```

(Unrelated to your current problem: the forced cast `as! String`
can crash at runtime, if the value is not present or not a string.
You should use optional binding instead.)