# HTML tags in String, convert to normal String

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

Html tags are coming in string from api response, need to display formatted string not with the tags. Below is my code what i tried:

html String:

```
"&lt;span class=&quot;st&quot;&gt;&lt;em&gt;Bread&lt;\/em&gt; is a staple food, usually by baking. Throughout ... &lt;em&gt;Sourdough&lt;\/em&gt; is a type of &lt;em&gt;bread&lt;\/em&gt; produced by dough using naturally occurring yeasts and lactobacilli. ... List of &lt;em&gt;toast&lt;\/em&gt; dishes&lt;\/span&gt;",
```

code tried:

```
let data = Data(vm.description!.utf8)
if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
        infoDescription.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

Other methods tried:

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Please guide what wrong i am doing or what is missing. Thanks

Comment: Seems related to the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decode html formatted text in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529174/how-to-decode-html-formatted-text-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode HTML entities first then you can use your current implementation to get your styled string.

For HTML entities decoding you can refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30141700/3867033

But I found that you can use NSAttributesString to achieve the same result.

```
let html1 = """
&lt;span class=&quot;st&quot;&gt;&lt;em&gt;Bread&lt;/em&gt; is a staple food, usually by baking. Throughout ... &lt;em&gt;Sourdough&lt;/em&gt; is a type of &lt;em&gt;bread&lt;/em&gt; produced by dough using naturally occurring yeasts and lactobacilli. ... List of &lt;em&gt;toast&lt;/em&gt; dishes&lt;/span&gt;
"""

extension String {
  var toAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    return try? NSAttributedString(
      data: data(using: .utf8)!,
      options: [
        .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
      ],
      documentAttributes: nil)
  }
}

let output1 = html1.toAttributedString!.string
let output2 = output1.toAttributedString
```

It's a little bit weird for me too, but it works...

[image]

Comment: What did you get? I did try it before posting here.

Comment: getting same value nothing changed

Comment: Are you sure? Please note that you have to call the `toAttributedString ` 2 times like the example above.

Comment: added a image to demonstrate what did I get from the `output2`

Comment: error on output1 : Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: earlier i misunderstood your answer and used only output 2 directly

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying but can you run the code now without any compile error?

Comment: Thanks, i would like to mention, i am already using the same method in extension class what did i miss there and what worked here, can you please clear me

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer, it's a little bit weird for me too but when you call the `toAttributedString` 2 times, you will get the result like me.  The first call (output1) will give you the html string with all the HTML entities are decoded. The second call using the `output1.string` as an input. Doing so you will get the what you want in the output2. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use below `String` extension to remove html tags from string

```
extension String {
    public var withoutHtml: String {
        guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return self
        }

        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]

        guard let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else {
            return self
        }

        return attributedString.string
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let formattedStr = yourString?.withoutHtml
```

Comment: getting same string nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I used scanner to convert html text to normal text and it works perfectly.

This function strips the text between `<` and `>` tag.

```
func stripHTML(fromString rawString: String) -> String {
    let scanner = Scanner.init(string: rawString)
    var convertedString = rawString
    while !scanner.isAtEnd {
        let _ = scanner.scanUpToString("<")
        if let text = scanner.scanUpToString(">") {
            convertedString = convertedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(text)>", with: "")
        }
    }
    return convertedString
}
```

Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner) to see a detailed explanation of how scanner works.

Use it as the code below. Enjoy :)

```
let normalText = stripHTML(fromString: yourHtmlText))
```

Comment: giving errors of ios 13 only check. On adding ios 13 checks in other classes started giving same error

Comment: Hello @iPhone7, this new scanner API can only be used on iOS 13. I believe if you add #available(iOS 13.0, *) above this function, this will work.