# Replacing string sections with quote in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I'm trying to replace some HTML codes in Swift with the appropriate characters. I used a String extension.

```
extension String {
    mutating func fix_HTML_Codes() {
        let originalString = self
        let newString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#039;", with: "\'")
        let newString2 = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&quot;", with: "\"")

        self = newString2
    }
}
```

However, instead of replacing my escaped single quote with a single quote, it actually replaces it with `\'`, anyone know why?

Here's an example of what I'm getting:

```
"On which Beatles album would you find the song \'Eleanor Rigby\'?"
```

It's including the escape character.

Comment: if you put it in a UILabel (for instance), do you see the back slash?

Comment: @Larme shoot I'm not sure let me give it a try. I was just looking in the debugger and assumed it was busted.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift

Comment: @Larme You are right, it displays correctly as intended, but in the debugger it shows it as the escape character with slash. Do you know why?