# Why when creating NSAttributedString from html sometimes app throws exception "The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have these extensions to parse string with html tags to NSAttributedString

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        Data(utf8).html2AttributedString
    }
}

extension Data {
        var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(
                data: self,
                options: [
                    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
                ],
                documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            bfprint("html2AttributedString: Html string parsing error: \(error)",
                    tag: LogUtils.Tags.criticalDevError,
                    level: .error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
}
```

The app gets original html strings from Localizable files. Sometimes when the app parses the html strings with <u> tag like this "This is <u>underlined part</u>" I see this error log:

html2AttributedString: Html string parsing error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."

I have read official doc and didn't find any pitfalls that could cause the problem. Also I didn't find any similar questions related to getting NSAttributedString

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Do you have an example string that actually causes the problem you're describing? That said, this API is [pretty famously terrible](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115405), and always has been. It is very buggy and has bizarre side-effects due to [pumping the runloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65387083/97337). I strongly recommend moving to the [async version](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/3335215-loadfromhtml). While less convenient, it is reliable. See also MartinR's: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30141700/97337.

Comment: One possibility is that you're using this on a non-main thread. This initializer is only valid on the main thread. This kind of error could happen due to cross-thread problems (though a crash would be more expected).

Comment: @RobNapier we have 8 versions for supported languages, and it happens very rarely sporadically even for one user. It is not reproducible.

I checked log and bugfender shows that it happens in main thread always.