How to remove HTML entities when Decoding JSON?
In Swift, I am trying to convert HTML entities that are coming back from an API that I am using. Does JSONDecoder have something that can do this?
class SoloViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var category: Int = 9
    @Published var difficulty: String = "easy"
    @Published var questionCount: Int = 10
    @Published var currentQuestionIndex: Int = 1
    @Published var status: TriviaStatus = .created
    @Published var questions: [Question]?
    
    func getQuestions() async throws -> QuestionResponse {
        print("Started")
        let endpoint = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=\(questionCount)&category=\(category)&difficulty=\(difficulty)&type=multiple"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else { throw TriviaError.invalidURL }
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw TriviaError.invalidResponse
        }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            return try decoder.decode(QuestionResponse.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print("ERROR we hit the last one")
            throw TriviaError.invalidData
        }
    }
}

I tried converting data to string and back after removing/converting the html but it didn't decode when I did that.
I could maybe go through the entire questions variable after decoding but that doesn't seem like the correct solution. I feel like there is an obvious solution that I am missing haha
Here are the structs...
struct QuestionResponse: Decodable {
    var results: [Question]
}
struct Question: Decodable {
    var type: String
    var difficulty: String
    var category: String
    var question: String
    var correctAnswer: String
    var incorrectAnswers: [String]
}

Paste this to see a response:
https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10
Example that I want converted:
What is the frontman&#039;s name of the metal band Megadeth?

I want &#039; to be converted to '
Here is the entire API response to understand what I am asking:
{"response_code":0,"results":[{"type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","category":"Entertainment: Music","question":"What is the frontman&#039;s name of the metal band Megadeth?","correct_answer":"Dave Mustaine","incorrect_answers":["Rob Halford","Vince Neil","James Hetfield"]},{"type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","category":"Geography","question":"What is the capital of Peru?","correct_answer":"Lima","incorrect_answers":["Santiago","Montevideo","Buenos Aires"]},{"type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","category":"Geography","question":"How many time zones does China have?","correct_answer":"1","incorrect_answers":["3","4","2"]},{"type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","category":"Science &amp; Nature","question":"What is the unit of electrical capacitance?","correct_answer":"Farad","incorrect_answers":["Gauss","Henry","Watt"]},{"type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","category":"General Knowledge","question":"When was Hubba Bubba first introduced?","correct_answer":"1979","incorrect_answers":["1984","1972","1980"]},{"type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","category":"Entertainment: Video Games","question":"What is the name of the world that the MMO &quot;RuneScape&quot; takes place in?","correct_answer":"Gielinor","incorrect_answers":["Glindor","Azeroth","Zaros"]},{"type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","category":"Science: Computers","question":"When did the online streaming service &quot;Mixer&quot; launch?","correct_answer":"2016","incorrect_answers":["2013","2009","2011"]},{"type":"multiple","difficulty":"hard","category":"Science &amp; Nature","question":"Which of the following are cells of the adaptive immune system?","correct_answer":"Cytotoxic T cells","incorrect_answers":["Dendritic cells","Natural killer cells","White blood cells"]},{"type":"boolean","difficulty":"medium","category":"Entertainment: Cartoon &amp; Animations","question":"Night on Bald Mountain was one of the musical pieces featured in Disney&#039;s 1940&#039;s film Fantasia.","correct_answer":"True","incorrect_answers":["False"]},{"type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","category":"General Knowledge","question":"What is the world&#039;s most expensive spice by weight?","correct_answer":"Saffron","incorrect_answers":["Cinnamon","Cardamom","Vanilla"]}]}

I want this to be Decoded into my data structures above.

While not specific to parsing JSON, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift for relevant info.

JSON is not supposed to encode characters using HTML entities. There's no reason to do so. If a special character is encoded, it is supposed to be encoded as \uXXXX where XXXX is a 4-digit hex code.

It looks like someone else's database. I guess the entries were submissions from some online HTML editors, so maybe you also want to check for tags like <em>. Anyway, this is not a responsibility of JSONDecoder

You could try using encode=url3986, such as:
let endpoint = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=\(questionCount)&category=\(category)&difficulty=\(difficulty)&type=multiple&encode=url3986"
Note, in Question you probably need var correctAnswer: String? and var incorrectAnswers: [String]?, you need to consult the docs to see if other fields
need to be optional. Note there are other encodings you can choose, see the docs.
